# DataFrame.str.replace() vs.DataFrame.replace() quirk

Tags: python, pandas, string

Let's say I have a Series of strings I want to replace:

```
       Position
0       Guard
1   Forward-Center
2      Forward
```

I have a dict I'd like to use for the replace values:

```
POSITIONS = {
     'Guard':'G',
     'Forward':'F',
     'Center':'C'
  }
```

My desired output is

```
    Position
0      G
1     F-C
2      F
```

When I try

```
df.Position.replace(POSITIONS)
```

I get

```
         Position
0           G
1     Forward-Center
2           F
```

And when I use

```
df.Position.str.replace(POSITIONS)
```

I get a `TypeError`

```
TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'
```

But when I use `str.replace()` without the dictionary, It works:

```
df.Position.str.replace('Forward','F')

         Position
0           G
1        F-Center
2           F
```

So I figured to get my desired output I could just chain the `str.replace()` together to get my desired output like so

```
df.Position.str.replace('Forward','F').str.replace('Guard','G').str.replace('Center','C')
```

But I hate chaining methods like this and it doesn't look as good as just passing a dict. Is there a way to achieve my desired output without having to chain multiple `str.replace()`? Why does `.replace()` work with the dict but `str.replace()` doesn't? Additionally, why doesn't `.replace()` take care of the hyphenated strings like `str.replace()`?

Comment: `str.replace()` needs two arguments -- the substring to match and what to replace it with. It doesn't work with a dictionary of replacements.

Comment: `Series.str.replace()` is for doing 1-to-1 substring replacements, just like the non-Pandas `str.replace()` function. `Series.replace()` replaces whole values, not substrings, and it allows the replacements to be specified in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

With `.str.replace()`, the first argument can be a regular expression, and the replacement can be a function. The function can look up the match in the dictionary.

```
df.Position.str.replace('|'.join(POSITIONS), lambda m: POSITIONS[m.group(0)])
```